# How to kill app in background after X Amount of time

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am working on an app where I am getting an access token which would be valid for 300 seconds.

If in case app moves into the background (say phone call) for more than 300 seconds, I have to kill the app in the background.

I am able to increase the time of the app in the background using any services (Location etc) but please guide me how to kill the app in the background once token time (300 seconds) has been expired.

Comment: Don't kill the app. It seems like a crash to the user. Well since it's in Background, it shouldn't be an big issue. What about checking the token life span instead and block everything is not valid anymore?

Comment: ok thanks, I have to open landing page of the app when coming in foreground after given expiry time. I got your point.

Comment: App killing is not allowed in ios.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this link.
https://www.raywenderlich.com/143128/background-modes-tutorial-getting-started [Section: Performing Finite-Length Tasks]

The example tells you how to get extra time to complete what you’re doing when the app gets into background.

Answer (score 0):

An app can be killed using

```
exit(0)
```

This would lead to exiting the RunLoop, but it may lead to AppStore rejection.